# launch two apps, Android nougat

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app for android nougat, when I click on a button I launch two apps at the same moment and the same screen.
I want to use this new feature of Android 7, Is it possible?

Comment: You do not control whether the device is in some form of multi-window mode or not. Only the user controls this.

Given that the device *is* in a multi-window mode, you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_TO_ADJACENT` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on an `Intent` with `startActivity()` to try to steer that activity to another window.

Comment: thanks for answer , i want like this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.keepawayfromfire.screens

Answer (score 4):

You can use Accessibility API for such feature. It doesn't require any permissions.

android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService has following apis:

`service.performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)` which you can use to initiate split screen mode.

`public List<AccessibilityWindowInfo> getWindows ()` to check wether split screen mode is on. Look for a window with  `AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_SPLIT_SCREEN_DIVIDER`

You also will need to play with intent flags when launching activities.

```
 val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeBasic().toBundle()?.apply {
     putInt(
         ActivityOptionsFlags.KEY_LAUNCH_WINDOWING_MODE,
         ActivityOptionsFlags.WINDOWING_MODE_SPLIT_SCREEN_PRIMARY
     )
     putInt(
         ActivityOptionsFlags.KEY_SPLIT_SCREEN_CREATE_MODE,
         ActivityOptionsFlags.SPLIT_SCREEN_CREATE_MODE_TOP_OR_LEFT
     )
 }

 startActivities(listOf(intentBottom, intentTop).toTypedArray(), options)
```

Using this accessibility apis and intent flags you can achieve your goal. Consult [this](https://github.com/stavangr/SplitScreenLauncher) repo by stavangr for detailed implementation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Comment: Thanks.. now this is not working for Android 13. do u know a solution for that?