# How to open another app in split mode [android]

Tags: android

If android work on split-screen mode, I can open the app in the second part of the screen.

But if android work on normal mode, I can't open the app in split-screen mode.

In android normal mode, How to use intent to open the other app in split-screen mode?

Comment: You may find your answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907094/programmatically-open-app-in-split-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907094/programmatically-open-app-in-split-screen)

Comment: This solution is only work when android split screen mode actived

Comment: As far as I know, opening app in split-screen mode requires both apps to support this feature. If the app you want to open in split-screen mode does not support it, you cannot force it to open in that mode through an intent.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Intent` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` to open the app in split mode.

Example

```
Intent i = getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package of the app you want to launch");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```