# Is there a way to programatically exit split-screen or free-form window mode in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, foreground-service, split-screen, freeform

I am currently using a slightly modified version of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591204) to open a free-form window of the currently open foreground app

```kotlin
private fun goToSplitMode() {
    val manager = packageManager
    val i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps") ? : return

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT |
        Intent.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_SINGLE_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    val mBounds = new Rect(getScreenWidth(applicationContext) / 4, 0, getScreenWidth(applicationContext) / 2, getScreenHeight(applicationContext));
    var mOptions = getActivityOptions();
    mOptions = mOptions.setLaunchBounds(mBounds);

    startActivity(i, mOptions.toBundle());
}
```

This works fine as is and opens google maps somewhere in a free-form window on the screen. The location or size doesn't matter to me right now.

**Does anyone know a way of now switching this window back to a full screen/normal window?**
I am doing all this from a foreground service by the way

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Things I have considered

- Closing and reopening the application

  - I can't seem to find a way to reliably do this for an activity outside of MY app
- Running a modified version of the code above to either set the bounds to be different or to use some combination of flags to try and change it back

  - Neither of these have worked and the free-form window doesn't change at all